# How to find the horizontal asymptote of $y=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I used computer to draw a graph of it and found there is a horizontal asymptote $y=e$, but I don't know what is the method to figure it out since it's not a rational function.

Comment: I saw a question with a similar function and I found that kind of helpful but I ended up with a different situation from that one. Anyone help me out I'll really appreciate!

Comment: Investigate $$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x+1}$$ too. Also think about the difference of these two functions.

Comment: What's your definition of $e$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is to prove that $\:y=(1+\frac{1}{x})^x\:$ tends to a finite value when $\:x\:$ tends to infinity.

Since we are more used to deal with limits around $\:0\:$, let $\:x=\frac{1}{t}\:$ with $\:t\:$ tending to $\:0\:$.

$$y=(1+t)e^{1/t}=e^{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}$$
$$\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=\frac{t+O(t^2)}{t}=1+O(t)$$
which tends to $\:1\:$ when $\:t\:$ tends to $\:\:0$. Hense $\:y=e^{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}\:$ tends to $\:e^1=e\:$ .

Comment: I dk who voted this A down.Looks perfect to me. For $0<t<1$ we have $\ln  (1+t)=t-t^2/2+t^3/3-...=t+O(t^2).$

Comment: Downvote might be because this answer uses knowledge about $e, x\mapsto e^x, x\mapsto\ln(x)$ and the taylor series for $\ln(1+x), |x|<1$ just to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

By definition, a function $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote $$y=a$$ if and only if

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=a$$

where $a$ is some real constants.

You can find out more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote).